# Android testing - How to trigger a system intent to be intercepted by a tested Activity

Tags: android, testing, android-intent, junit, nfc

My application has an activity which is listening for intents and reacting to the system event ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED. When such intent occurs, the app reads the tag and redirects the user to a screen displaying the content read on the tag.

I've started implementing automated tests and am now facing this challenge : I can navigate through my app to the screen I was talking about, but now to make the test completely automatic, I'd like to trigger an ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED intent with a hard coded content to make the activity navigate to the result page. In spite of my searching, I haven't found what I was looking for.
Is this doable ? If so, how am I supposed to proceed ?

I'm using Android Espresso along AndroidJUnit4.